# Android SQLite - Wrong column when drop and re-create table with same table name

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am writing an Android app that use SQLite. But I found problem with getting SELECT result's column when re-create a table with same table name. Here is the code snippet:

```
package com.info.abc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class TestActivity2 extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = TestActivity2.class.getSimpleName();

    public SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String mPath = Main.DB_PATH + "test.db";

        Log.e(TAG, ">>>>>>>> in openDB " + mPath);


        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);


        gosql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TT1");

        gosql("CREATE TABLE TT1 ('STAFFID' varchar, 'STAFFNAME' varchar)");
        getDbTableDetail("TT1");

        gosql("INSERT INTO TT1 ('STAFFID', 'STAFFNAME') VALUES ('999', 'Tim')");
        gosql("SELECT * FROM TT1");

        gosql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TT1");  // Empty result

        // Drop table and Re-create with different column name
        getDbTableDetail("TT1");

        gosql("CREATE TABLE TT1 ('FIRSTNAME' varchar, 'LASTNAME' varchar)");
        getDbTableDetail("TT1");

        gosql("INSERT INTO TT1 ('FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME') VALUES ('F', 'L')");
        gosql("SELECT * FROM TT1");



        mDataBase.close();

    }


    public void getDbTableDetail(String table) {
        Cursor c = mDataBase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='" + table + "'", null);
        int i = 0;

        Log.e(TAG, "getDbTableDetail() - " + table);
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            String[] temp = new String[c.getColumnCount()];
            for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = c.getString(i);

                Log.e(TAG, "c.getColumnNames() = " + c.getColumnNames()[i] + ", temp[i] = " + temp[i]);

            }

        }

    }


    public synchronized void gosql(String sql)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "gosql() = " + sql);

        Cursor result = null;


        if (sql.startsWith("SELECT"))
        {
            try {
                result=mDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);

                Log.e(TAG, "SQL result");
                result.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    for (int i=0; i<result.getColumnNames().length; i++)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, result.getColumnNames()[i] + " = " +result.getString((result.getColumnIndex(result.getColumnNames()[i]))) );
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, " ");

                }while(result.moveToNext());

                result.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "gosql SELECT error:");
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            } finally {


            }
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                mDataBase.execSQL(sql);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "gosql execSQL error:");
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Logcat output:

```
gosql() = DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TT1
gosql() = CREATE TABLE TT1 ('STAFFID' varchar, 'STAFFNAME' varchar)

getDbTableDetail() - TT1
c.getColumnNames() = type, temp[i] = table
c.getColumnNames() = name, temp[i] = TT1
c.getColumnNames() = tbl_name, temp[i] = TT1
c.getColumnNames() = rootpage, temp[i] = 4
c.getColumnNames() = sql, temp[i] = CREATE TABLE TT1 ('STAFFID' varchar, 'STAFFNAME' varchar)

gosql() = INSERT INTO TT1 ('STAFFID', 'STAFFNAME') VALUES ('999', 'Tim')

gosql() = SELECT * FROM TT1
SQL result
STAFFID = 999
STAFFNAME = Tim

gosql() = DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TT1

getDbTableDetail() - TT1

gosql() = CREATE TABLE TT1 ('FIRSTNAME' varchar, 'LASTNAME' varchar)

getDbTableDetail() - TT1
c.getColumnNames() = type, temp[i] = table
c.getColumnNames() = name, temp[i] = TT1
c.getColumnNames() = tbl_name, temp[i] = TT1
c.getColumnNames() = rootpage, temp[i] = 4
c.getColumnNames() = sql, temp[i] = CREATE TABLE TT1 ('FIRSTNAME' varchar, 'LASTNAME' varchar)

gosql() = INSERT INTO TT1 ('FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME') VALUES ('F', 'L')
gosql() = SELECT * FROM TT1
SQL result
STAFFID = F
STAFFNAME = L
```

Obviously, the second SELECT result returns data with WRONG COLUMN NAME and getColumnIndex() does not work as expected. I have spent a whole day on trying to figure it what's wrong, but no luck.

Is it impossible to re-create table with same table (with correct column name)?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to get correct column name when I SELECT the data after create the table with same table second time.

Comment: The getColumnNames() always returns the column names that I create first time, which is wrong.

Comment: What are the reasons for dropping a table and recreating it?

Comment: p.s. You should learn about Java's enhanced for loop.

Comment: I need to generate the UI from customized XML which contains SQL statement. The existing XML reuse the table name of temporary table. That's why I need to get the correct column names.

Comment: In theory, what you have shown should not be possible. Please add another statement `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='TT1'` after the DROP, and after the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: I edited the question and added getDbTableDetail() to output the date from sqlite_master. But still have no idea of why getColumnNames() return wrong names and make getColumnIndex() does now work as expected

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

- try to disable WAL (write ahead log) mode
- for "select" queries try to enumerate columns explicitly

**Details**:

I faced similar problem, WAL was enabled and my scenario was like this:

1. Drop table X
2. Create table X with different column set
3. Make db.query(X, null, null, ...) call (pay attention, that second arg ("columns") is null)
4. **Problem**: resulting cursor on cursor.getColumnNames() call gives me list of old column names - as if drop + create weren't executed at all! But about 1-2 minutes later getColumnNames() gives correct set of columns.

Then if I disable WAL mode, cursor.getColumnNames() immediately gives me correct columns.

Also I tried to enabled WAL again, but modify query by passing list of all my columns (db.query(X, arrayOf(C1, C2, ...), null, null, ...)) - it works for me too